# A measure of correlation

Tags: correlation, order-statistics

Consider a random pair $(X,Y)$ with some distribution (with finite moments of all order). Let us sample $(X_i,Y_i), i = 1,\dots,n$ IID with the same distribution as $(X,Y)$. Assume that $n = 2m$ is even. Let $I=(i_1,i_2\dots,i_n)$ be indices that put the sequence $(Y_i)$ is increasing order, i.e., $Y_{i_1}\le Y_{i_2} \le \dots \le Y_{i_n}$. Consider looking at the sum (or say maximum?) of empirical variances of $\{X_{i_1},\dots,X_{i_m}\}$ and $\{X_{i_{m+1}},\dots,X_{i_n}\}$ and call it $R_n$.  Letting $n \to \infty$, it seems to me that $R_n$ converges to a number which is a measure of correlation between $X$ and $Y$. Is this related to a known correlation measure?

Comment: As best I understand this, you are summing the variances of X's only. Why would that be related to correlation?

Comment: @gung because the $X$s are ordered according to $Y$, it seems

Comment: @gung, yes, because of what ssdecontrol said. Consider the case Y = X versus the case where X and Y are independent.

Comment: Consider the case where X and Y are marginally ~ uniform(0,1). If the order of $(Y_i)$ matches that of $(X_i)$ (i.e., they have the same rank statistic), then the variance of each of those halves will be reduced by a factor $\approx 1/4$ for large n, whereas if they are independent, it stays $\approx$ the same.

Comment: The idea is interesting.  However, the formulation does not work as a measure of correlation because the result is in the units of measurement of $X$, whereas any number measuring a correlation really ought to be unitless (and ideally has universal meaningful bounds, such as $0$ for no correlation and $1$ for perfect correlation).  You might consider instead taking the mean of the empirical variances of the two halves of the $X$ data *divided by* the empirical variance of all the $X$ data. Subtracting this from $1$ could be interpretable as a form of correlation.

Comment: @whuber, yes, you are right, I was interpreting "correlation" in a general sense. What I have is more like a measure of covariance. Properly scaled as you mentioned can be turned into a measure of correlation.